# android spinner performClick onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner

I have a little problem with a `spinner`.

I create a `Spinner` the user click a Button. The `Spinner` is shown as it should be, but when `onItemSelected` should be called nothing happens.

Here is the code

```
public void setUpSpinner(){
    spinner = new Spinner(this);
    CustomArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getAsStrings());
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view) {       
    spinner.performClick();
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {        
    String getName = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
    getListFromName(getName);
}
```

Anyone knows what is wrong here?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding a `Spinner` in my `xml` with height and width set to zero.

Comment: @Bastaix Could you please tell how you declare the Spinner.

Comment: not working in my case. How did you created spinner after that, means whether 1. = new Spinner(...)  OR  using = findViewById(...) ??

Comment: Finally worked. Had to add  android:spinnerMode="dialog" in xml for spinner

Comment: Brilliant, never thought about that

Answer (score 0):

This looks enough like the turorial, so refer back to that. See below:

I don't see this, but does the main class implement OnItemSelectedListener? Also, You'll want to instantiate the Spinner inside the onCreate() within the main class body.

This line needs to be within the onCreate();

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

Comment: The spinner is instantiated in the onCreate where the `setUpSpinner()` is called, and the class implements onItemSelectedListener.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have `spinner = new Spinner(this)` in the set-up ?

surely you already have a Spinner in the XML of your layout, then you simply do `spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.WHATEVER_THE_ID_IS_IN_THE_XML);` so you don't need a `new`

P.S. this is how I define a Spinner in an XML layout

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/SPINNER_ID"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```