# Control spinner after click button

Tags: android, events, spinner

I want to show spinner element after click to TextView.
I use the next code

```
    final Spinner spin = new Spinner(context);
    String[] tlt = {"Apple", "Orange", "Plum"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tlt);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                    Log.v("itemNO", position+"");
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    // your code here
                }

            });
    spin.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lang);
    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spin.performClick();
        }
    });
```

In my .xml file only TextView present (may be it's wrong?)
After TextView click appear Spinner menu but when I choose some item nothing happen. It looks like setOnItemSelectedListener() does not work.

Have you any ideas?
Thank you for answers!

Comment: I didnt see where Spinner add to layout?

Comment: may be this in case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555549/android-spinner-performclick-onitemselected

Comment: Thank you!!! The last link helped me!!! I simple added spinner to .xml with zero width and height. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example from the google developer site:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

You should add the Spinner to the xml file.