# How to programmatically show spinner pop up in android

Tags: android, spinner

I am facing a problem about spinner. Suppose an spinner dialog is pop up and if in that time locking of screed occur when I unlock the screen the spinner pop up is not shown there. Can anyone suggest me any solution of this or can anyone know how to pragmatically pop up spinner dialog in onResume.

Comment: code is required here which you have did to show spinner popup

Comment: Yes I want to know can you know any way to forcefully show spinner pop up window in program

Answer (score 18):

Try `spinner.performClick();`. For me it is working.

Comment: Please also check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555549/android-spinner-performclick-onitemselected

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679804/possible-to-programmatically-open-a-spinner-in-android-app

Comment: The difference between when it works and when it doesn't is the UI thread. You can only call that method from the UI thread so the onResume would need to set a runonUI in order to invoke.

Comment: When using a dialog my spinner gets open behind the dialog using performClick(); Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```